# Escape false is not working in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.2 and I have used `escape=false` for the `outputText` to display the output.  This is not working for me.

```
val = "<ol><li>sfsfsd</li><li>fgsdsdg</li></ol>"
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{dummyBean.val}" />
```

It is not displaying the numbers instead I am getting a dot (.) on display.

I am gettting output like :

```
. sfsfsd
. fgsdsdg
```

But the expected output is :

```
 1.sfsfsd
 2.fgsdsdg
```

Comment: did you try just #{dummyBean.val} in your xhtml?

Comment: yes i tried and it is not working

Comment: it given <ol><li>sfsfsd</li><li>fgsdsdg</li></ol>"
as output

Comment: i want the output like 1.sfsfsd
 2.fgsdsdg

Comment: if generated html contains html tags from your string it is not a render problem. i think it is CSS or DOM related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A weird idea:
what if the html is indeed escaped but you have some styling issue which hides the numbers before the dots. I would try to add some left padding either to the printed list

```
<ol style="padding-left: 100px;">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
</ol>
```

or to the span itself

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{dummyBean.val}" style="padding-left: 100px;"/>
```

and see what happens.

Comment: oh it's working i had div for the output text it hides the text actualy.Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is just a different way to style an ordered list.

You just need to add this style

```
ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're using `ol` rather than `ul`?